# multiple calls to utl_smtp.write_raw_data to attach blob-file

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a valid file stored in a PL/SQL blob variable `attachment_blob_`.  Assuming that the file is of a small enough size, the following procedure works to attach the file to the e-mail.

```plsql
PROCEDURE Write_Mail_Attachment IS BEGIN
    Write_Part_Boundary (OUTER_BOUNDARY_);
    utl_smtp.write_data (
        smtp_conn_,
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; ' ||
        'name="' || attachment_name_ || '"' || utl_tcp.crlf ||
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.crlf ||
        'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'||attachment_name_||'"'||utl_tcp.crlf||utl_tcp.crlf
    );
    utl_smtp.write_raw_data (smtp_conn_, utl_encode.base64_encode(attachment_blob_));
END Write_Mail_Attachment;
```

(Just to avoid ambiguity or "did you check this" kind of answers, all variables *are* valid. Any variables not defined in this block belong to the parent scope.)

My problem starts when the variable `attachment_blob_` is larger than a certain size.  It becomes too big to be processed by the `utl_encode.base64_encode()` function, and produces a numeric or value error.

Okay, that's fine, I tell myself.  All I need to do is break the `blob` up into multiple chunks.  So I modify the procedure as follows:

```plsql
PROCEDURE Write_Mail_Attachment IS
    chunk_size_    NUMBER := 1900;
    offset_        NUMBER := 1;
    file_chunk_    RAW(1900);
BEGIN
    Write_Part_Boundary (OUTER_BOUNDARY_);
    utl_smtp.write_data (
        smtp_conn_,
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; ' ||
        'name="' || attachment_name_ || '"' || utl_tcp.crlf ||
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.crlf ||
        'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'||attachment_name_||'"'||utl_tcp.crlf||utl_tcp.crlf
    );
    WHILE offset_ < Dbms_Lob.GetLength(attachment_blob_) LOOP
        Dbms_Lob.Read (attachment_blob_, chunk_size_, offset_, file_chunk_);
        utl_smtp.write_raw_data (smtp_conn_, utl_encode.base64_encode(file_chunk_));
        offset_ := offset_ + chunk_size_;
    END LOOP;
END Write_Mail_Attachment;
```

So now, this procedure executes without error because the chunk-size never gets too large for `utl_encode.base64_encode()` to manage.  But now the problem is that the attached file is corrupted when it arrives in my inbox.

When I investigate the "raw" email content, I can see that the attachment-content string is trimmed to roughly 1900 characters.  If I define the `block_size_` variable to be `50` (instead of `1900`) then the raw content in the e-mail is truncated to about 50 characters instead. In other words, it's as though the procedure `utl_smtp.write_raw_data()` is overwriting the previous part of the file-content on each iteration of the loop, so that I only ever end up with the last chunk of the file in the e-mail when it is sent.

I have verified the documentation on `utl_smtp.write_raw_data()`, which confirms that the e-mail message will be appended to, rather than overwrite the last chunk.

I have also searched Oracle message-boards for solutions, (indeed, my second procedure above is derived from some postings I found there).  However, I haven't been able to send the attachment fully in-tact yet.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that Base64 encode 3 bytes into 4 bytes and uses '=' when last group contains less then 3 bytes, check padding section on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Character '=' can be placed only at the end of the encoded document. That's why your buffer length has to be a multiple of three.

Comment: You seem to have got the right answer, (although your explanation isn't the clearest).  I need to do more testing first, but if you don't mind, I'll clarify your answer before marking it as accepted.

Comment: Yes.  The number `1900` doesn't divide by 3 nicely.  Change it to `1902`, and the program works.  That's a pretty subtle "feature" (bug??) that I cannot find documented. On the Oracle pages from where I got the code, nobody spotted the issue!